# If I want to include the Template 10 code project (and not only through GitHub) how can I do?

Tags: template10

I supposed I have to include only the project available in "Template 10 (Library)" folder (as it is for the example projects available in the Template 10 solution), but if I do so and I try to compile it, I get this error related to Snippets folder:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "call "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\Nuget\Build.cmd" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\bin\x86\Debug\" "Template10Library" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\"
call "C:\Data\projects\URBELOG PROJECTS\Urbelog10\Urbelog10\Snippets\InstallSnippets.cmd"" exited with code 1. Template10 (Library)

Comment: Could you confirm you are running Debug+x86?

Comment: Is this an error in Output or an error in the Errors Window?

Comment: Yes I am running in Debug x86 and the error is listed in the Error List window

Comment: I tried again:

    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The command "call "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\\Nuget\Build.cmd" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\bin\x86\Debug\" "Template10Library" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\"
call "C:\Data\projects\URBELOG PROJECTS\Urbelog10\\Snippets\InstallSnippets.cmd"" exited with code 1. Template10 (Library)

Comment: I simply added Template10(Library) in the solution and added it in the other project reference [project created from Hamburger Template10 (deleting the GitHub reference to Template10)] ... then build all

Comment: I tried again now downloading with TortoiseGit the last version of the Template 10 solution, but referencing the Template10(Library) from an other project [even a project created from Hamburger Template10 (deleting the GitHub reference to Template10)] ... then build all ... I continure to receive the same error

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The command "call "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\\Nuget\Build.cmd" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\bin\x86\Debug\" "Template10Library" "C:\Data\projects\GitHub\Template10\Template10 (Library)\"
call "C:\Data\projects\URBELOG PROJECTS\Urbelog10\\Snippets\InstallSnippets.cmd"" exited with code 1. Template10 (Library)  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the Template10 project and Remove the Post-build event command line, under build events.